# How to include a nominal independent variable two or three times in a regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, categorical-data

So my logistic regression model aims to predict the likelihood of a severe accident (yes/no) based on the characteristics of drivers, car types and other factors. I have data which has all this information for the past three years.

When looking at car type, I'm unsure how to include it in my model since there are at least two drivers who each have a car type. I thought about having a multitude of binary variables which state whether there was at least one car type a,b,c,d etc involved in the accident.

The problem I'm having trouble with is having dealt before with categorical variables within logistic regression before - I normally only have one car type that would be listed as 1 (yes) with all the others as zero. Here, there is a potential for 1's existing 2 or 3 times.

I'm not really sure how to deal with this. Does it work within the logistic regression equation? Or is there some sort of relationship going on within the variable? Or does some sort of interaction when combining car type 1 and car type 2 have some effect rather than independently?

Comment: Interesting problem, I'm not sure of the solution, but you will have the same problem for types of drivers, since there will be multiple drivers if there are multiple cars.

Comment: Yep also proving to be a problem!

Comment: What is the unit of analysis here, drivers? Maybe you can share with us how your data look like.

Comment: Do you have information on the car (driver) that *caused* the accident, so that you can include just that one? Alternatively including all applicable dummies for one observation is valid but makes the (quite strong) assumption that the log-odds per dummy will be equal across all possible combinations.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same thing! Information isnt included on the dataset re who caused the accident unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by unit of analysis? Each row is an accident and then characteristics of driver 1 and driver 2 (as well as type of car 1 and type of car 2) are in columns. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Exactly, so drivers are nested in accidents, right? Is it possible that a diver in one accident is also a driver in another accident?

Comment: yes...? how does this resolve the issue?

Comment: That is possible yes

Comment: But I dont think that makes a difference. If the driver is involved in a separate accident, the characteristics of that accident may be different and hence the new accident adds new information to the data set regarding the characteristics influencing a severe accident

Comment: Suppose you have only three car types, A, B and C, and also suppose you confine yourself to accidents with only two cars. Then you would have six combinations of car types AA, BB, CC, AB, AC and BC. Then you could use dummies for the combinations. Just an idea ...

Comment: Yes that works! I think I'll need to perform some EDA in order to figure out which two car types to choose.

Comment: One practical solution is to use *impact coding* for massively categorical variables like zip codes. It's described in this article, among others  https://win-vector.com/2012/07/23/modeling-trick-impact-coding-of-categorical-variables-with-many-levels/

Answer (score 1):

A practicle solution is this one. Suppose you have three car types A, B and C, and two drivers 1 and 2. Your "basic" model would then look like this:

```
Y = b0 + b1*B1 + b2*C1 + b3*B2 + b4*C2
```

B1 and C1 are 0/1 dummies for car types B and C for driver 1.
B2 and C2 are 0/1 dummies for car types B and C for driver 2.
Car type A is the reference for both drivers.

It makes sense to let the Y difference between B and reference A be equal for both drivers; also the difference between C and A. Therefore the following model seems obvious:

```
Y = b0 + b1*B1 + b2*C1 + b1*B2 + b2*C2
```

And this can also be written as:

```
Y = b0 + b1*(B1+B2) + b2*(C1+C2)
```

This means that new variables, say BB and CC, must be created, with BB=B1+B2 and CC=C1+C2; and these can be entered in the model as predictors:

```
Y = b0 + b1*BB + b2*CC
```

Note that BB and CC have values 0, 1 or 2, being the number of drivers with car types B and C, respectively. The interpretation of b1 is:

"the difference in Y if one of the drivers changes from car type A (the reference) to car type B".

So, b1 is the difference in Y between an accident with car types AA and AB; but also between AC and BC. In both situations one A changes into a B.

Further, if both drivers change from A to B, then the difference in Y is 2*b1! This is the case when you compare an "AA accident" with a "BB accident".

Hope this is clear? Regards, Ben.

The range of values of BB and CC change, dependent on nr. of drivers involved in an accident. For 2 drivers it's 0-2, for 3 drivers it's 0-3 etc. However, I guess that b1 can still be interpreted as what happens if óne car type would change from reference into B or C. I did not verify this by writing out equations, but I guess it must hold. Maybe Frank could confirm this. This would mean that you can analyse accidents with different nr.'s of drivers this way.

Comment: This seems reasonable and it exposes what is being assumed: that the average of the two drivers and two cars is what matters.  But since the difference between them may matter, you may need to remove the restriction you placed and deal with 4 parameters.  A question remains: How does one uniquely define driver 1?   This won’t affect the average but it will affect the difference.  If there is no unique choice then modeling the average and the absolute difference may be the way to go.

Comment: As far as I understood, there is no difference between driver 1 and 2, they are exchangeable, and do not play a particular role in the accident. At least, that role is unknown.

Comment: If there were only 2 car types then taking the average and the absolute difference would make sense.  With multiple categories this would involve indicator variables for all categories but perhaps a simplification for the absolute difference to some measure of differences between the cars, e.g. absolute difference in weights of cars.  Given model names you can look up weights.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. The only thing I'm struggling to wrap my head around is - if I reduced the no of vehicle types to 3 and no of drivers to 2 - would I need to reduce my dataset to include only those accidents and perform regression on them or could I keep the rest of the dataset and the coefficients for the vehicle types would be zero if none of the 3 types of vehicle were included? If that makes sense? But then I guess the value for A would be left if the coefficients are 0? So one of the choices would have to be made out of all the vehicle types. You couldn't just have none?

Comment: It seems that there may be many car types so it’s hard to reduce them perhaps.  I think it would be better to use some quantitative variables instead, e.g. cost, length, weight, then a few types such as SUV, pickup truck, truck?

Comment: Or the car types could be grouped differently so that they fit into say - 1 of 3 groups?

Comment: I added a paragraph at the end of my answer above, about having varying nr.'s of drivers. If you would decide to follow Frank's idea to use use quantitative variables instead of types, you can use the same trick of summing, say, the lengths, as for the dummies.

Answer (score 1):

I like `BenP`’s answer but I have a different approach in mind. This is how I imagine your data based on your comment:

| acc_ID | severe | age_d1 | car_d1 | age_d2 | car_d2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 24 | a | 19 | a |
| 2 | 0 | 56 | b | 38 | b |
| 3 | 0 | 34 | b | 43 | c |
| 4 | 1 | 18 | a | 27 | c |
| 5 | 0 | 65 | c | 34 | b |

Each row is a different accident. Columns represent the characteristics of drivers (e.g., `age_d1`, `age_d2`) and types of car (`car_d1`, `car_d2`, etc). Your outcome is whether the accident is severe or not (`severe`).  I ignore the fact that same driver could involve in different accidents, etc.

Now, we can reshape this data into long format:

| acc_ID | severe | driver | age | car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 24 | a |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 19 | a |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 56 | b |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 38 | b |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 34 | b |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 43 | c |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 18 | a |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 27 | c |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 65 | c |
| 5 | 0 | 2 | 34 | b |

As you can see, we have two observations for each accident (it could be more if there are more cars/drivers) and single columns for characteristics and car type.

If you *could* ignore this nested structure, you can simply use car type to predict severity of accident. If not, you could estimate a model with severity being accident-level (level-2) outcome and car type driver/car-level (level-1) predictor (maybe you also have accident-level predictors, e.g., time of accident). There are different strategies to estimate such models for nested data. Now, this could not provide the information in `BenP`’s answer (e.g., when car types change for both drivers vs. the single driver) or combined effect of types, but it might be useful for some applications.

Comment: You can't perform logistic regression when there is multiple accident ID's since then there is duplicate data for other variables (e.g. speed limit the accident took place in). As part of the assumptions for logistic regression there needs to be one row per accident.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there are modeling strategies taking into account this nested structure, for example multilevel logistic regression. You can use them and there could be other options.